# jQuery, sortable: modify the "clickAt"

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I have the following draggable list items structure:

```
<ul id="dadCol_0" class="dad-list ui-sortable">
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl1" style="position: relative;">1</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl2" style="position: relative;">2</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl3" style="position: relative;">3</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl4" style="position: relative;">4</li>
<li class="dad-item ui-draggable" id="sl5" style="position: relative;">5</li>
</ul>
```

Now it doesnt matter when you click inside the rectangle to start draging - but I want it to be the center of this rectangle (width / 2, height / 2). I somewhat need using the `clickAt` property I guess, but heres a little example what Ive done so far:

```
$('.dad-item').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
        opacity: 0.6, 
    });
});
```

this does the opacity, but the dragging is broken now: the items wont change the order, no revert triggering etc.

EDIT: 2nd try:

```
dad_list.sortable({
    connectWith: 'ul.dad-list',
    containment: '#containment',
    items: 'li.dad-item',
    cursorAt: {
        top: $(this).height()
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        serializedads();
    }       
});
```

and now I cant move it up-down, only horizontally

Comment: similar like this: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement when I modify the draggable() property, that item goes wrong.

Comment: Check my answer. Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
$('.dad-item').draggable({
    opacity: 0.6,
    cursorAt: {
        left: width / 2,
        top: height / 2
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle for this. I am not able to guess how you are  using these.

Comment: are you sure the top property is OK?

Comment: Yea. It is documented on jQuery documentation

Comment: You wanted to do draggable or sortable?

Comment: sortable, oops it looks I failed this